# What's the issue with +0 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why do `37291+05472` and `37291+5472` give different output?

```js
console.log(37291+05472)
```

```js
console.log(37291+5472)
```

Comment: This is a non-standard extension only allowed in sloppy mode. Do not rely on it. Do not use leading zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting a [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Integers) with `0` declares that is an [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8) and not a decimal (base 10).

Comment: How can I set `05472` to be decimal? I tried `d05472` just now, but it throws error

Comment: Just don't put a `0` in front of it! `5472`